# "Update" button disabled in GitHub Desktop

Tags: github-desktop

I'm using GitHub Desktop for code management. I've created a branch for some code changes to my project, I've committed those changes, and now I want to merge the branch back to the master branch. The [GitHub instructions for doing this](https://help.github.com/desktop/guides/contributing/syncing-your-branch/) indicate I need to click the "Update to master" button to perform the merge. Unfortunately, that button is disabled in my case. If I hover over the "Update to master" button the tooltip states " is up to date with master". Yet if I switch back to the master branch it is clear my code changes are not yet in the master branch.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong? How can I convince GitHub Desktop that my code changes do indeed need to be merged to the master branch?

Comment: Update to master means that you are trying to push your master branch to the github remote. You need to merge this branch into master.

Comment: @EliSadoff: I thought "Publish" was the button that pushed to the remote? Do I have to use the git shell to perform a local merge?

Comment: I learned the answer: You can merge a feature branch back the master branch by switching to the master branch and then click the Compare button and select the feature branch from the pop-up menu. Now the Update button will merge the feature branch to the master.

Comment: Put that in an answer! You are allowed, and encourage to answer your own question

Answer (score 0):

I learned the answer: You can merge a feature branch back the master branch by switching to the master branch and then click the Compare button and select the feature branch from the pop-up menu. Now the Update button will merge the feature branch to the master.